# Ideablade Update

Tags: sql-server-2005, devforce

I'm using IdeaBlade version 3.6. I noticed the following generated SQL update query :

> (@P1 nchar(32),@P2 nvarchar(32),@P3 nvarchar(512),@P4 nchar(32),@P5 int,@P6 nvarchar(32),@P7 int,@P8 datetime,@P9 datetime,@P10 datetime,@P11 int,@P12 datetime,@P13 int,@P14 int,@P15 int,@P16 nvarchar(32),@P17 nvarchar(128),@P18 nvarchar(32),@P19 nvarchar(32),@P20 datetime,@P21 datetime,@P22 bit,@P23 nvarchar(32),@P24 nvarchar(64),@P25 nchar(32))update "dbo"."GSS_Documents" set "DocumentID"=@P1,"FileName"=@P2,"FilePath"=@P3,"BusinessOfficeID"=@P4,"Pages"=@P5,"FileSize"=@P6,"DocumentType"=@P7,"DateCreated"=@P8,"EffectiveDateCreated"=@P9,"DateProcessed"=@P10,"ProcessorID"=@P11,"DateReviewed"=@P12,"ReviewerID"=@P13,"WorkflowStatus"=@P14,"ApprovalStatus"=@P15,"AccountNumber"=@P16,"AccountName"=@P17,"SerialNumber"=@P18,"TransactionID"=@P19,"CriticalDate"=@P20,"EmergencyDate"=@P21,"GenerateSMSAlert"=@P22,"CustomerPhoneNumber"=@P23,"CustomerEmailAddress"=@P24 where "DocumentID"=@P25

Problem is DocumentID is the primary key. This update appears to be updating the primary key as well! Any ideas on how to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

You're using Entity Framework in this example and we don't tell EF how to do its job. Perhaps you're changing the PK (I rather doubt it). Follow up with us directly ... especially with regard to DevForce 2010 which relies on EF v.4.